# Multiple Full Outer Joins

Tags: sql, impala

I want to use the result of a `FULL OUTER JOIN` as a table to `FULL OUTER JOIN` on another table. What is the syntax that I should be using?

For eg: T1, T2, T3 are my tables with columns id, name. I need something like:

```sql
T1 FULL OUTER JOIN T2 on T1.id = T2.id   ==> Let this be named X

X FULL OUTER JOIN T3 on X.id = t3.id
```

I want this to be achieved so that in the final ON clause, I want the T3.id to match either `T1.id` or `T2.id`. Any alternative way to do this is also OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE(X.id,t3.id) AS id, *-- specific columns here instead of the *
FROM 
    (
       SELECT COALESCE(t1.id,t2.id) AS id, * -- specific columns here instead of the *
       FROM T1 FULL OUTER JOIN T2 on T1.id = T2.id
    ) AS X
    FULL OUTER JOIN T3 on X.id = t3.id
```

Comment: @sagi Oooowkay, hand and feet it is.

Comment: :PP , didn't mean to upset

Comment: @sagi No worries ;-), I understand.

Answer (score 3):

Often, chains of full outer joins don't behave quite as expected.  One replacements uses `left join`.  This works best when a table has all the ids you need.  But you can also construct that:

```
from (select id from t1 union
      select id from t2 union
      select id from t3
     ) ids left join
     t1
     on ids.id = t1.id left join
     t2
     on ids.id = t2.id left join
     t3
     on ids.id = t3.id
```

Note that the first subquery can often be replaced by a table.  If you have such a table, you can select the matching rows in the `where` clause:

```
from ids left join
     t1
     on ids.id = t1.id left join
     t2
     on ids.id = t2.id left join
     t3
     on ids.id = t3.id
where t1.id is not null or t2.id is not null or t3.id is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like you suggested, using IN()

```
FROM T1
FULL OUTER JOIN T2
 ON(T1.id = T2.id)
FULL OUTER JOIN T3
 ON(T3.ID IN(T2.id,T1.id))
```

or I think you can do it with a UNION (depends on what you need) :

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT name,id from T1
    UNION
    SELECT name,id from T2) x
FULL OUTER JOIN T3
   ON(t3.id = x.id)
```

Comment: I get this error when I use IN(): NotImplementedException: Error generating a valid execution plan for this query. A FULL OUTER JOIN type with no equi-join predicates can only be executed with a single node plan.

Comment: Did you try to run it or run execution plan on it? try to run it first @Abhishek

Comment: I ran the query in Impala which resulted in this error.